# OSX - Package a shell based interactive binary

Tags: node.js, macos

I've created a small NodeJS script that compiles down using [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/) so the app becomes its own binary. The app is meant to run in Terminal and be interactive with the user. I'd like to package this in a .app so it feels like a full application that regular users can run.

How can I go about this? I've so far tried Platypus with mixed results as it doesn't seem to exit correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

- Use `[Apple]Script Editor` to create a new script and save it as an *application*.
- Place your binary - let's call it `foo` - in the new `.app` bundle's `Contents/MacOS` subfolder.
- Place the following code in the application's AppleScript:

```applescript
set embeddedBinary to POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/MacOS/foo"

tell application "Terminal"
    do script quoted form of embeddedBinary
    activate
end tell
```

When you run the application, the embedded binary is opened in a new Terminal window that you can interact with.

Append `& "; exit"` to the `do script` command to automatically close the Terminal window when the binary terminates.

Note, however, that your **application merely act as a *launcher* for the embedded binary**:

- It terminates after the Terminal window has been created
- so its Dock icon only shows up briefly and disappears again
- and you'll get no application menu (which wouldn't be an option anyway, given that your binary runs in Terminal).
- Every time you start the app, a *new* Terminal window is opened, even if your binary is already running in one.

There are ways to address these issues (except the menu one), but they require additional work - see below.

---

A **solution that addresses above issues** for a **more integrated experience**:

- It keeps the wrapper application open (showing its own Dock icon).
- It *relays activation* to the launched Terminal window running the embedded binary when the app is activated (e.g., by clicking on the Dock icon)
- The wrapper application terminates automatically  when the launched Terminal window is closed.

However, it has **limitations**:

- Sadly, to relay activation, **GUI scripting is needed**, which requires a **one-time authorization with administrative privileges** on any given machine; the user is prompted on first launch, but it requires a few steps.
- For the application to be able to quickly relay activation when clicked and to quickly quit when the Terminal window closes, its `on idle` event handler must be invoked frequently, which consumes CPU resources, although the extra load on the CPU is pretty small - see comments in source code below.

**Instructions:**

- Use `[Apple]Script Editor` to create a new script and save it as a *stay-open* *application*:

  - In the `Save` As dialog, choose format `Application` and check the `Stay open after run handler` checkbox.
- Place your binary - let's call it `foo` - in the new `.app` bundle's `Contents/MacOS` subfolder.
- Place the following code in the application's AppleScript:

```applescript
# Global variable to track the launched Terminal window (tab).
global g_winLaunched

on run

    # Get full path of embedded binary.
    set embeddedBinary to POSIX path of (path to me) & "Contents/MacOS/foo"

    tell application "Terminal"
        # Launch embedded binary in new Terminal window, and
        # have the window closed when the binary terminates *successfully*.
        # This leaves the window open in case of error - whether on
        # initial launch or on existing - giving the user a chance to investigate.
        do script quoted form of embeddedBinary & " && exit"
        set g_winLaunched to front window
    end tell

end run

on idle
    if frontmost of me then # If this app is activated, relay activation to the launched Terminal window.
        try
            # Activate the running window using GUI scripting.
            # Sadly, `set index of g_winLaunched to 1` is NOT enough to activate the window.
            # NOTE: This requires that this app be authorized for assistive access via
            #           System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility.
            tell application "System Events"
                perform action "AXRaise" of window (name of g_winLaunched) of process "Terminal"
            end tell
            activate application "Terminal"
        on error
            tell me to quit # Window is no longer alive, quit this app.
        end try
    else
        # See if tab is still alive, and, if not, quit this app.
        try
            id of g_winLaunched
        on error
            tell me to quit
        end try
    end if
    # Call this handler every N seconds.
    # This is a trade-off between responsiveness and CPU usage.
    # With 0.3 secs., CPU usage of this app is around 0.8%
    # on my 3.2 Ghz quad-core Intel Core i5 iMac.
    return 0.3
end idle
```

Comment: Going to give this a shot later in the weekend! Thanks. And what kind of additional work are we talking about?

Comment: @Dustin: My pleasure; re additional work: see my update. It works reasonably well, but the downside is the need to authorize the app for assistive access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JXcore](http://jxcore.com) which offers native packaging (self executables) of Node.JS apps with a single command, like:

```
$ jx package myapp.js MyApp -native
```

Then you can just run it on OSX (or other unix systems):

```
$./MyApp
```

For Windows (if you would ever need it) the file name would be `MyApp.exe`.

More on this here: [Packaging & Code Protection](http://jxcore.com/docs/jxcore-feature-packaging-code-protection.html).

Comment: EncloseJs already compiles it in a binary like jxcore , what I wanted was to properly package it in an application bundle.